# REST API endpoint selection in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, rest, endpoint

Given a controller like this:

```
   @RestController
   @RequestMapping("/cars") {
   public class CarController{

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ResponseEntity<List<Cars>> getCars() { //logic }

   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET")
   public ResponseEntity<List<Cars>> searchCar(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("value") String value) { //logic}
  }
```

If the url is like this localhost/cars I would like to access the getCars() method.

But if the url is :
localhost/cars?name=something&value=100 or

localhost/cars?name=something or

localhost/cars?value=100

I would like the second method to be accessed.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, I would recommend to use just "/car" endpoint for second method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still asking for the same list of resources, cars, only thing is that you are adding a filter or search / query criteria.

It would be beneficial to develop a query filter / criteria to support something like:

```
/cars?q=make+eq+acura (meaning make=acura)
/cars?q=price+lt+25000  (meaning price <25000)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. because when a request comes to container then it will 1st scan all the URL and check uniqueness of the URL. If there is duplicate URL present then container will throws exception.

In your case you are using class level URL mapping, but you are not using method level URL mapping.

To access your  `getCars()` method you need to use some URL like below

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

To access your 2nd method you need to use another mapping URL

```
@RequestMapping(values="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET")
```

You can't access

```
localhost/cars?name=something&value=100 or

localhost/cars?name=something or

localhost/cars?value=100
```

as you are using 2 parameters like `@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("value") String value`
you need to pass two parameter in your url like below

```
localhost/cars/test?name=something&value=100
```

if you don't want to pass any of two parameter then just pass it as `null` and check it inside your method